# Tangent plane to a surface that is parallel to another plane

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

**Given:**
surface S: $x^2+y^2+4z^2=16$
plane $\pi$: $x+y+2\sqrt2z=10$

1. Find all points (a,b,c) such that tangent plane to S at (a,b,c) is parallel to $\pi$
2. Find all tangent planes to S parallel to $\pi$

**My knowledge:**

I realise that the given surface is an ellipsoid and the given surface is flat, so I'm expecting 2 such points.

I know that 2 surfaces are parallel if their gradients are parallel.

I know that 2 vectors are parallel if they are scalar multiples of each other.

**My attempted solution:**
$grad(\pi) = [1,1,2\sqrt2]$
$grad(S) = [2x,2y,8z]$

How to proceed?

Comment: Find the points where the gradients are parallel ($\nabla S = k\nabla \pi, k \ne 0$). Hint for the first component (with $k=\pm 1$): $2x= \pm 1$).

Comment: So I arrived at the points of the following form: P=$(\frac{k}{2},\frac{k}{2},\frac{k}{2\sqrt2})$. How do I find k? Plug into the equation of S?

Comment: Remember that the points must lie on the surface (use the surface constraints).

Comment: So I found the points P1=$(2,2,\frac{2}{\sqrt2})$,$P2=(-2,-2,\frac{-2}{\sqrt2})$. The coordinates are opposite, which makes sense considering S is an ellipsoide. Now I'm trying to find the equation of planes through points P1, P2, parallel to $\pi$

Comment: Remember $(v-p) \cdot n = 0$ gives you a plane equation, where $p$ is a point on it, and $n$ is the normal ($v$ is a vector). $\cdot$ is the scalar (dot) product.

Comment: Finally got the planes:  $x+y+2\sqrt2z-8=0$ and $x+y+2\sqrt2z+8=0$ 
I think my teacher expects me to use the partial derivative formula for tangent plane passing through a point:
$fx(P)(x-xp)+fy(P)(y-yp)+fz(P)(z-zp)$
where fx,fy,fz are partial derivatives of the surface and xp,yp,zp are coordinates of the point. Thank you for help!

Comment: You can avoid introducing the extraneous variable $k$ by stating the parallel condition as $\nabla S\times\nabla\pi=0$. This generates three linear equations, two of which are independent. Their solution is a line that intersects $S$ at the points of tangency.

Answer (score 1):

The ellipsoid center is at $p_0=(0,0,0)$ now at the tangency points we have

$$
\nabla S = \lambda \nabla \pi
$$

or

$$
\lambda(x,y,4z)=(1,1,2\sqrt 2)
$$

but $p_0+\lambda(x,y,4z) = p_0 + (1,1,2\sqrt 2)$ pertains to the ellipsoid then

$$
\frac{1}{\lambda^2}(1^2+1^2+4(2\sqrt 2)^2) = 16
$$

so we have

$$
\lambda = \pm\frac 12\sqrt{\frac {17}{2}}
$$

so the contact points are

$$
p_i = \pm\frac{1}{\lambda}(1,1,2\sqrt 2),\ \ \, i \in\{1,2\}
$$

The planes consequently are given by

$$
(p-p_i)\cdot \nabla\pi = 0,\ \ \, i \in\{1,2\}
$$

with $p = (x,y,z)$